# GridView OutOfMemory Bitmap

Tags: java, android, memory, gridview, crash

So i have the problem that my app is crashing because of OutOfMemory.

There are really good and a lot of solutions first **my Adaptercode**:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.accidentally_open_internet_explorer,
            R.drawable.angry_shaking,                               R.drawable.are_you_fucking_kidding_me, 
            R.drawable.angry_with_pc,
            R.drawable.sample_7,                                R.drawable.awkward_moment,
            R.drawable.awkward_moment,                          
            R.drawable.beer_guy,                                
                                        R.drawable.beng,
            R.drawable.accidentally_open_internet_explorer,     R.drawable.boobs,
            R.drawable.big_smile,                               R.drawable.cereal_guy,
            R.drawable.challenge_accepted_drunk,                            R.drawable.challenge_accepted,
            R.drawable.bad_pokerface,                           R.drawable.challenge_considered,
            R.drawable.challenge_denied,                            R.drawable.challenge_failed,
            R.drawable.classic_rage,                                    R.drawable.one_does_not_simply,
            R.drawable.computer_stare,                  R.drawable.computer_slice,
            R.drawable.concentrated,                    R.drawable.concentrate,
            R.drawable.concentrated_teeth,                      R.drawable.cry_pc,
            R.drawable.dat_ass,                                 R.drawable.desk_flip,
            R.drawable.double_facepalm,                                 R.drawable.duck_yeah,
            R.drawable.fap,                                 R.drawable.fap_accepted,
            R.drawable.fap_gentleman,                               R.drawable.feels_good_man,
            R.drawable.forever_a_gamer,                                 R.drawable.forever_alone_clean,
            R.drawable.forever_alone_sad,                               R.drawable.forever_alone_together,
            R.drawable.fuck_that_bitch_yao_pff,                                 R.drawable.fuck_that_yao_ming,
            R.drawable.fuck_yeah,                       R.drawable.fuck_yeah_close_enough,
            R.drawable.gentleman_troll,                                 R.drawable.happy_smoking,
            R.drawable.haters_gonna_hate,                           R.drawable.if_you_know_what_i_mean_mr_bean,
            R.drawable.if_you_know_what_i_mean_mr_bean_blank,                           R.drawable.if_you_know_what_i_mean_mr_bean_blank,
            R.drawable.impossibru,                          R.drawable.indeed,
            R.drawable.jesus,                                   R.drawable.keyboard_break,
            R.drawable.knowthatfeel,                    R.drawable.like_a_sir,
            R.drawable.long_long_neck_surprise,                     R.drawable.look_from_bottom,
            R.drawable.me_gusta,                        R.drawable.me_gusta_creepy,
            R.drawable.me_gusta_makeup,                                 R.drawable.not_sure_if_gusta,
            R.drawable.now_kiss,                                R.drawable.one_does_not_simply,
            R.drawable.sample_1,                                R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_7,                                R.drawable.sample_12,
            R.drawable.sample_13,                               R.drawable.today_is_monday,
            R.drawable.trees_smile,                                 R.drawable.trees_stoned,
            R.drawable.trees_stoned_exhale,                                 R.drawable.trees_stoned_inhale,
            R.drawable.wonka,                               R.drawable.y_u_no,
            R.drawable.yea_science,                                 R.drawable.you_are_the_man


    };


    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

.....
```

Then i tried 2 Solutions:

```
First:

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //This actually is a bad solution, because every time convertView is reused, you will still initialize new ImageView, which is wrong
    //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
    //new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
    //return imageView;

    //Better solution
    ImageView imageView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
        new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
        //create new ImageView if it is not present and populate it with some image
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        //re-use ImageView that already exists in memory
    }

return imageView;
}


class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImageAdapter.this.mContext.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 70));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

**But my problem is that the pictures are on each other so they lie on top of each other why???**

2 Solution:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        //  TextView txt = new TextView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(
              new  GridView.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   
         Bitmap m_d = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), 
                                           mThumbIds[position]);
        if (m_d != null)
        {
             Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(m_d, 205, 205, true);
             imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
        };
        return imageView;}}
```

**But that´s laggy as hell why???**

thank you dudes for helping!!!

Comment: @Mocialov Boris Could you help me too first solution code is from you would be very nice!

Comment: I think you're right that opening a new question is probably best rather than adding a new one to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a Bitmap using BitmapFactory, you must be sure to call `.recycle()` on that bitmap instance when you're done with it, or else you'll very quickly run out of memory.

Your first solution is closer to correct because you need to recycle those convertView objects, so just make sure that your convertView exists, *and* that you've recycled any bitmaps that it might already be holding onto before you create new ones.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // clean up your old bitmap first, if there is one.
    if(imageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        imageView.setDrawable(null);
        if(bd.getBitmap() != null){
            bd.getBitmap().recycle();
        }
        bd = null;
    }

    new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);


    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it´s working now :)! All pictures are working now! And what can i do that the pictures not appear so slowy?

Comment: I'm at work right now, so can't look into it too deeply.  Thing to remember is that decoding bitmaps does take time, and on some devices it will be slow, so perhaps you could have a placeholder image to represent a loading state.

Comment: Ok no problem i will take a look at placeholder tomorrow maybe it´s solving the problem with rotate too.

Thank you for your help i´m happy that bitmap is working :) !!

Comment: Glad to help.  Let us know what you come up with for your loading time issues!

Comment: Added something in my question i found today.